# mysql select from multiple tables but if id can't be found on the other 2 set a default value of null to the column

Tags: mysql, select

currently im having a problem on how to query this. my current query is like below

```
  SELECT tbl1.col1,
  tbl1.col2,
  tbl1.col3,
  tbl1.col4,
  tbl1.col5,
  tbl2.col1,
  tbl2.col2,
  .
  .
  .
  tbln.col1,
  tbln.col2,

  FROM tbl1,tbl2,...tbln
  WHERE tbl1.col1= tbl2.col1AND
  .
  .
  .
  tbl1.col1= tbln.col1;
```

but i can't show/display those rows that didn't exist in the other tables.

what i really want to do is still show those that didn't exist in other tables,
but if the specific data doesn't exist in other table it'll just display a null in the column.

```
  SELECT tbl1.col1,
  tbl1.col2,
  tbl1.col3,
  tbl1.col4,
  tbl1.col5,
  iff(tbl2.col1 <> null,tbl2.col1,NULL),
  iff(tbl2.col2 <> null,tbl2.col1,NULL),
  .
  .
  .
  iff(tbln.col1 <> null,tbl2.col1,NULL),
  iff(tbln.col2 <> null,tbl2.col1,NULL),

  FROM tbl1,tbl2,...tbln
  WHERE tbl1.col1= tbl2.col1 AND
  .
  .
  .
  tbl1.col1= tbln.col1;
```

Comment: is `tbl1` the main table here? by that i mean that is it the table wherein `tbl2` and `tbl3` are the child tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  tbl1.col1, tbl1.col2, ...
  tlb2.col1, tbl2.col2, ...
  tlb3.col1, tbl3.col2, ...
  ...
  tlbn.col1, tbln.col2, ...
FROM tbl1
  LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.col1 = tbl2.col1
  LEFT JOIN tbl3 ON tbl1.col1 = tbl3.col1
  ...
  LEFT JOIN tbln ON tbl1.col1 = tbln.col1
```

This will cause all columns from `tbl2` to be `NULL` if an entry doesn't exist in that table for the corresponding entry in `tbl1`. And the same for all the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why you are using `iff`

try with `if`

```
   if(tbl2.col1 <> null,tbl2.col1,NULL),
```

you can show null values by using `LEFT JOIN` in your case you will do hundreds of if statments but with `left join` is shorter and easier